# WinPE as installation tool

Tags: windows, foreman

I have succesfully created a WinPE image which includes a simple script to auto-install windows. This image is used to boot via PXE. As soon as WinPE is "booted" it asks the server which windows image it must install (these images are out of scope of the question).

I'd like to make this WinPE publicy available for general purpose (it does not add any functionality beyond aformentioned the small script); however, I was wondering if I am allowed to redistribute this (even in my own company) if I only use it for installing a windows OS? Or will I have unwanted legal attention?

## Full disclosure

I'm using foreman to automatically commission my windows servers. As it took my some time to get this working (a day or two at least), I would like to give something back to the community: out-of-the-box integration of windows deployment in foreman (of course excluding installation media, that's definitely illigal)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is basically a question for legal advice, [which is off topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider Windows PE executives as a tiny Windows OS.
You cannot make them publicly available for download.

**Edit**; 
Some software companies distribute their Windows PE based tools but they must have a distribution agreement with MS.

Comment: Okay, understood. Work-around here is probably to ask an interested party to install WAIK via the official way and run a script which automatically builds all of the above?

Comment: You got it; that's the way.